# Android studio not showing the original layout that exist on hard disk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Everything worked fine yesterday. Toady after opening android studio project it's showing error like this image.
[image]

But when I see in the hard disk this layout is OK. I tried invalidate cashes / restart.

That file on hard disk.
[image]

Comment: is this project reverse engineered?

Comment: No. It's not  reverse engineered.

Comment: can you please check activity_main.xml location. It would be in res -> layout folder.

Comment: Yes, it's there. But when I open that layout file it's showing like 1st image. But when i go back to my pc's hard disk that layout file showing like 2nd image. And there are more layout file, all are changed into like 1st image.

Comment: check your encoding then